# Installing JBOSS 4.2.3.GA and Wildfly 10.1.0.Final side by side - Pitfalls?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I would like to *install* on my workstation (Windows 7), for study, debug & development purposes, **both** `JBOSS 4.2.3.GA` and `Wildfly 10.1.0.Final`.

I do not intend to *run* them at the same time. That is, only one of them is supposed to be up at any given moment.

Are there any pitfalls that should I watch out for? (for example, overwriting some common DLLs, conflicting environment variables)

Comment: I hope not. I currently have 32 different versions of JBoss and WIldFly installed side by side. I've been accumulating them since JBoss 4.0 or thereabouts. This is on a Mac though, FWIW.

Comment: There won't be any issues with DLL. WildFly 10 need Java 8. Install it along with lower version you have been using for jboss 4. Set Java 8 path in wildfly script.